# Suppose that $V$ is a complex vector space with $\text{dim} V= n$ and $T \in L(V)$ is such that $\text{Ker}(T^{n−2}) \neq \text{Ker}(T^{n−1})$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that $V$ is a complex vector space with $\dim V= n$ and $T \in L(V)$ is such that $\ker(T^{n−2}) \neq \ker(T^{n−1})$
> Prove that $T$ has at most two distinct eigenvalues.

The solution said that $0$ is an eigenvalue but I am not sure why that has to be the case. What if $0$ is not an eigenvalue? What would be the contradiction here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that $\text{Ker}(T^i) \subseteq \text{Ker}(T^{i+1})$, for any $i\ge 0$.

Remark that if $\text{Ker}(T^k) = \text{Ker}(T^{k+1})$ for some $k\ge 0$ then one has $\text{Ker}(T^i) = \text{Ker}(T^{i+1})$ for every $i\ge k$. This fact can be proved easily by an induction.

By the hypothesis, $\text{Ker}(T^{n-2}) \subsetneq \text{Ker}(T^{n-1})$, hence there is no $0\le k \le n-2$ such that $\text{Ker}(T^k) = \text{Ker}(T^{k+1})$. Therefore, we get the following strictly ascending chain:
$$ 0 = \text{Ker}(T^0) \subsetneq \text{Ker}(T^1) \subsetneq \ldots \subsetneq \text{Ker}(T^{n-1})$$
Hence, $\text{dim} \ \text{Ker}(T^{n-1})$ can be either $n-1$ or $n$.

If $\text{dim} \ \text{Ker}(T^{n-1}) = n$, then actually $T^{n-1} = 0$, so all the eigenvalues of $T$ are $0$.

We remain with the case $\text{dim} \ \text{Ker}(T^{n-1}) = n-1$. By the Rank-Nullity theorem, $\text{dim} \ \text{Im}(T^{n-1}) = 1$. Since $0 = \text{Ker}(T^0) \subsetneq \text{Ker}(T^1)$, we get that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. Assume that $T$ has two nonzero eigenvalues $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$. Consider $v_1$ and $v_2$ the corresponding eigenvectors. Since $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$, the vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent. (It is a pretty well-known fact. If you don't know it, try to prove it as an exercise.) Now, just note that $T(v_i) = \lambda_i v_i$, implies that $T^{n-1}(v_i) = \lambda_i^{n-1} v_i$, with $i=1,2$. Thus, $\text{Im}(T^{n-1})$ contains two linearly independent vectors, which is a contradiction to the fact that $\text{dim} \ \text{Im}(T^{n-1}) = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

If $0$ is not  an eigenvalue then $T$ is invertible and so is any power of $T$. Hence, $ker (T^{n-2})=ker(T^{n-1})=\{0\}$.